# How can I determine this equation?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

I have an equation that have been formulated as:
$$\Delta w_{ki}=\eta (y_{k}-y_{o})(x_i-x_o)+a_1,$$
where$$y_{k}=\sum_{j}w_{kj}x_{j}+a_{2}$$

and where $a_1,\eta,x_o ,y_o$ and $a_2$ are constants and $E[x_i]=E[x_j]=\mu$. 
and the matrix $C$ denote the covariance matrix of the $x_i,x_j$ with its $ij$-th element defined by 
 $$c_{ij}=E[(x_i-\mu)(x_j-\mu)].$$
Can anyone help me determine the $\Delta w_{ki}$ in terms of $C$ and $\mu$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best you can do is to find $E\Delta w_{kj}$.

Comment: @fedja: Can you help me How to do it to obtain the equation in terms of covariance martrix?